# Restrict Convertflow Script to specific pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have added a convertflow script in my public pages default layout like this:

```js
head() {
  return {
    script: [
      {
        async: true,
        src: link of the script,
      },
    ],
  }
},
```

Since it is an async call the pop up of convertflow shows when it becomes fully available. i.e. sometimes even in the admin and user pages as well. So, is there a way to restrict the script to be run only on my public pages?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot restrict a JS script to be used only on specific paths. Or at least not on an SPA which updates the DOM rather than repaints a fresh new page on each navigation.

Meanwhile, as seen during the install, it looks like that you can configure the thing to be available only on some specific pages: https://youtu.be/Rk3llM6bCvc?t=237

It looks customizable enough, with some regex and so on I guess.

---

Here is a quick little visual of the UI allowing to do it

[image]

Comment: This will be great in case the admin or client pages are loaded first but since the public pages are being loaded and on condition, URL does not contain admin and client are met it is being loaded again

Comment: I did not quite get the issue here. But you probably will not be able to achieve anything better than hiding in a dirty way or using something hacky. At the end, people should not have access to it if they don't have the permissions, no?